# Proper way of allocating array together with its owner

Tags: c++

I am trying to dynamically allocate an array of generic type along with kind of primitive control block. Take this as an examplary code of this "control block":

```
template<class T>
struct my_array{
    T* arr;
    unsigned size;
};
```

To avoid multiple allocations I try to call allocating `new` only once. This is code I came up with:

```
template<class T>
my_array<T> *alloc_new_array(unsigned size){
    unsigned align_mismatch = sizeof(my_array<T>) % alignof(my_array<T>);
    unsigned array_size = size * sizeof(T);
    unsigned struct_size = sizeof(my_array<T>) + align_mismatch ? 
        alignof(my_array<T>) - align_mismatch : 0; 

    char *memory = new char[array_size + struct_size];

    my_array<T> *arr = new (memory) my_array<T>;
    arr->arr = new (memory + struct_size) T[size];
    arr->size = size;
    return arr;
}
```

What I am concerned with is:

- correctness - I think I took care of struct padding, but there may be something I am missing. Did I count it correctly and will it work properly regardless of platform?
- standard compliance - don't I break any C++ rule and cause UB? I am aware I am doing some pointer magic here and I am unsure if everything is fully legal

Comment: Did you mean `T* arr` ?

Comment: `new T[n]` uses implementation specific size, and so cannot really be used for placement new. you have to placement new each element. But then, pedantically, `arr[2]` would be UB as you do pointer arithmetic outside of bound (as you don't have an array).

Comment: `alignof(my_array<T>)` should be `alignof(T)`.

Comment: Or alternatively: `template<class T> struct alignas(std::max({std::alignment_of_v<T>, std::alignment_of_v<T*>, std::alignment_of_v<unsigned>})) my_array {/*..*/};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One example for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <memory>
#include <numeric>

template<class T>
struct alignas(T) WithArray {
    unsigned const size_;

    static void* operator new(size_t size, unsigned elements) {
        return ::operator new(size + elements * sizeof(T));
    }

    static void operator delete(void* p, size_t /*size*/, unsigned /*elements*/) {
        return ::operator delete(p);
    }

    static void operator delete(void* p) {
        return ::operator delete(p);
    }

    T* get_elements() { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(this + 1); }

    T* begin() { return get_elements(); }
    T* end() { return get_elements() + size_; }

    WithArray(unsigned elements)
        : size_(elements)
    {
        std::uninitialized_default_construct_n(get_elements(), size_);
    }

    ~WithArray() {
        std::destroy_n(get_elements(), size_);
    }

    WithArray(WithArray const&) = delete;
    WithArray& operator=(WithArray const&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    unsigned elements = 10;
    std::unique_ptr<WithArray<int>> a(new (elements) WithArray<int>(elements));

    for(int& elem : *a)
        std::cout << elem << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::iota(a->begin(), a->end(), 0);

    for(int& elem : *a)
        std::cout << elem << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

`alignas(T)` + `reinterpret_cast<T*>(this + 1)` is the C++ version of C99 flexible array member.